# Find AMR silent packets

Tags: c++, encode, voice-recognition, audio-processing, amr

I am using opencoreamr library in a real-time project.I see that the library has a kind of VAD functionality which makes the noise packets silence.I want to distinguish the noise packets from voice ones which decode to the silence packets.How can I do that?How can I distinguish AMR silent packets (in order to not process them)?

Comment: Can you access the sample data? If so, the silent ones are the ones where the samples are all 0.

Comment: Yeah as I didn't find a simple way for doing that I call decode method after encoding of audio frame and then check all its value to see if it is 0 or not.I was searching of a more optimum way for doing that but it seems it works fine without adding sensible delay.